# The host 'smtp' could not be found

Tags: vba, outlook, smtp, email, outlook-2003

I am getting the following error while sending mail by click of a button in MS access form

I am using sendObject to send mail using vba code.

> The host 'smtp' could not be found.
>   Please verify that you have entered
>   the server name correctly. Account:
>   'pop3', Server: 'smtp', Protocol:
>   SMTP, Port: 25, Secure(SSL): No,
>   Socket Error: 11001, Error Number:
>   0x800CCC0D

Points to note:

- I am able to send and receive mails
  in my outlook; Problem is only when
  send mails through VBA access
  application.(Means it is not a
  outlook client configuration problem)
- When i copy paste the Vba application to another PC, i could
  successfully send emails without any
  error. (means this is not a vba
  access application problem)

Please help.

Comment: can you add your code that is doing teh mail send as it not clear what lib u r are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the SMTP server "smtp" is available from your second machine and not the first, or else there is some change to the mail settings and/or security when moving between the two machines.

Is your SMTP server actually called 'smtp'?

Comment: Nope i guess its something else , where i could check in another computer where a outlook is installed which is working??

Comment: Outlook SMTP server name is in the registry. For Outlook 2003 it is:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\[Profile]\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\